# Split one table into multiple tables based on the condition of the column using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```html
As of now I have done with ng-if and I have created custom directives.

<div class='tbl-container' ng-show='data.length > 0 && !loading'>
   <extype></extype>
</div>
<div class='tbl-container'  ng-show='data.length > 0 && !loading' >
   <extype2></extype2>
</div>

Then I have created individual tables in html with ng-if

<table class='smp-tbl' id='details-pane'>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Activity</th>
   <th>Zone</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Start Time</th>
   <th>End Time</th>
   <th>Elapsed Time</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-if="item.zone === 'USA'" ng-repeat='(key, item) in highLvlDetails' class='clickable'>
   <td ng-click='viewDetials(key, dc)'>{{ key }}</td>
   <td ng-click='viewDetials(key, dc)'>{{ item.zone }}<span><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
   <td ng-click='viewDetials(key, dc)' ng-class='{ complete: item.status === "COMPLETE", running: item.status === "RUNNING", started: item.status === "STARTED" }'>{{ item.status }}</td>
   <td ng-click='viewDetials(key, dc)'>{{ item.startTime }}</td>
   <td ng-click='viewDetials(key, dc)'>{{ item.endTime }}</td>
   <td ng-click='viewDetials(key, dc)'>{{ item.elapsedTime }}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to display multiple tables in one single page based on the content of a column. for example:

```html
<tr>
  <th>Activity</th>
  <th>Zone</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Start Time</th>
  <th>End Time</th>
  <th>Elapsed Time</th>
</tr>
```

If zone = "USA" then a different table should appear in page with all the zones USA similarly if zone = "UK", another table should appear. In this I have multiple zones and I want multiple tables to appear in a page. I am not sure how to do that in angularjs. Please help me to this.

Comment: share what you have tried so far in code

Comment: As of now I have done with ng-if and I have created custom directives.<div class='tbl-container' ng-show='data.length > 0 && !loading'>
   <extype></extype>
  </div>
  <div class='tbl-container'  ng-show='data.length > 0 && !loading' >
   <extype2></extype2>
  </div>

Comment: how you decide which zone is there. i mean how you decide if it is USA or UK

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if For this,
    Here is an example, this will help

```
<table ng-if="zone=='USA'">
<tr>
  <th>USA Activity</th>
  <th>USA Zone</th>
  <th>USA Status</th>
  <th>USA Start Time</th>
  <th>USA End Time</th>
  <th>USA Elapsed Time</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table ng-if="zone=='UK'">
<tr>
  <th>UK Activity</th>
  <th>UK Zone</th>
  <th>UK Status</th>
  <th>UK Start Time</th>
  <th>UK End Time</th>
  <th>UK Elapsed Time</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes ng-if could be a solution but what if I have 10-20 zones. Is there any other option.

Comment: @shraddha i believe your `Object model` should be modified not the table structure

Comment: then define me properly whether you need select one zone or display all of the zones' data...